# In celery how to get the task status for all the tasks for specific task name?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

In [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) i want to get the task status for all the tasks for specific task name. For that tried below code.

```
import celery.events.state

# Celery status instance.
stat = celery.events.state.State()

# task_by_type will return list of tasks.
query = stat.tasks_by_type("my_task_name")

# Print tasks.
print query
```

Now i'm getting empty list in this code.

Answer (score 3):

`celery.events.state.State()` is a data-structure used to keep track of the state of celery workers and tasks.  When calling `State()`, you get an empty state object with no data.

You should use `app.events.Receiver`(Stream Processing) or `celery.events.snapshot`(Batch Processing) to capture state that contains tasks.

Sample Code:

```
from celery import Celery

def my_monitor(app):
    state = app.events.State()

    def announce_failed_tasks(event):
        state.event(event)
        # task name is sent only with -received event, and state
        # will keep track of this for us.
        task = state.tasks.get(event['uuid'])

        print('TASK FAILED: %s[%s] %s' % (
            task.name, task.uuid, task.info(),))

    with app.connection() as connection:
        recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
                'task-failed': announce_failed_tasks,
                '*': state.event,
        })
        recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Celery(broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')
    my_monitor(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't natively supported. Depending on the backend (Mongo, Redis, etc), you may or may not be able to introspect the contents of a queue and find out what's in it. Even if you do, you'll miss items currently in progress.

That said, you could manage this yourself:

```
result = mytask.delay(...)
my_datastore.save("mytask", result.id)
...
for id in my_datastore.find(task="mytask"):
    res = AsyncResult(id)
    print res.state
```

Answer (score 0):

In celery you can easily find the status of task by accessing them through task ID if you want to access them from other function.

**Sample Code:-**

```
@task(name='Sum_of_digits')
def ABC(x,y):
   return x+y
```

> Add this task for processing

```
 res = ABC.delay(1, 2)
```

> Now use the task **res** to fetch the state, status and results(res.get())

```
 print(f"id={res.id}, state={res.state}, status={res.status}")
```